# How can I use DOMStringMap in TypeScript?

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

Let's say I have a function:

```
angular.forEach(myElements, function prepareElements(myEl: HTMLElement, index) {
    myEl.dataset.myProperty = "whatever";
})
```

The problem I get is 
`error TS2094: The property 'myProperty' does not exist on value of type 'DOMStringMap'`

I don't really understand the `interface` in `lib.d.ts`

```
interface DOMStringMap {
}
declare var DOMStringMap: {
    prototype: DOMStringMap;
    new (): DOMStringMap;
}
```

then later on...

```
interface HTMLElement {
    dataset: DOMStringMap;
    hidden: boolean;
    msGetInputContext(): MSInputMethodContext;
}
```

Is it just me or is this a little unclear?

I tried casting it `<DOMStringMap>myEl.dataset.myProperty = "whatever"`, which did nothing...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The DOMStringMap interface is empty because the spec is not finalized : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMStringMap

In the meantime you can simply use: myEl.dataset['myProperty'] = "whatever";

Comment: That construction causes `tslint` to warn that "object access via string literals is disallowed". `let p = "myProperty"; myEl.dataset[p] = "whatever"` works, but eww…

Comment: @mjs you can set tslint to ignore that warning

Answer (score 0):

you can also cast it to user defined type

```
type IType = {myProperty: string}
....
(myEl.dataset) as IType.myProperty = "whatever";
```